# Download zip using jszip in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, zip

Hi I am looking for solutions insanely for almost 2 days.I have sharepoint library where multiple word docs uploaded.Using javascript [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) I like to pass sharepoint file urls into it.Is this possible ?

I am getting each file server relative URL by ecmascript.Now I would like to do something like this:

```
  function create_zip() {
    debugger
        var zip = new JSZip();
        zip.add("http://myspsite/shareddoc/a/test.docx", "\n"); //this is hardcoded for testing??here I have file url
        //zip.add("hello2.txt", "Hello Second World\n");
        content = zip.generate();
        location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
    }
```

Any pointers or how I proceed from here?
Thanxs.

Comment: What is the point of zipping the file? Because your code means you'll download it, and then you'll zip it locally. So it doesn't save the bandwidth because you'll have to locally download it to be able to zip it... So what's the final purpose? Also, if I look at the JSZip document, there is no "add()" function... it's called ".file()", and it's only for a local file, not a remote file....

Comment: ok to be precise I would like to give user a zipped file that shud contain the files not indiviual download prompt .

Answer (score 0):

It´s insanely but interesting. Could works. Creating a button and calling the library and the script, I´m sure of that.

or, try this: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com.ar/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-windows-explorer-view.html

This is more simple.